# The requested resource is not available. JSP program error

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I am trying my forst jsp login program. It shows the login page correctly, but when I submit it gives the error:

HTTP Status 404 - /UserPass/username

type Status report

message /UserPass/username

description The requested resource is not available.

Here's my code:

```
username.java

package sid;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class username extends HttpServlet{

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        String user=request.getParameter("username");
        String pass=request.getParameter("password");

        if(user.equals("sid") && pass.equals("hello"))
        {
            System.out.println("Welcome");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid username or password");
        }
    }
}
```

user.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login Page</h1> 
<center> 

<form action="username" method="GET"> <br/>
User :<input type="text" name="username"> <br/>
Pass :<input type="password" name="password"> 
<br/><input type="submit" value="Submit"> </form> 
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>sid.username</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/username/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My user.jsp code is in WebContect, and my web.xml is in WebContent/WEB-INF/lib.
I am using Eclipse Indigo SR2 and Apache Tomcat.

Comment: What happens for `/UserPass/username/foo`? Additionally, while this may be a useful exercise to learn how servlets work, I strongly recommend against hand-writing them. For real-world programs, use a framework such as Spring MVC that handles all the boilerplate details for you.

Comment: Nothing happens there. After login, I just want it to display on console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your `web.xml` in `/WEB-INF`, not in `lib`.

Also, you will need to restart the server for your changes to reload and reflect.

Comment: Nothing changed. Same error.

Comment: I just tried your program in my machine and it is working when i put web.xml in /WebContent/WEB-INF and gives 404 when i put it in /lib. Can you post your screen shot of project's directory structure?

Comment: I restarted eclipse and it worked. Dont know how that fixed it.

Comment: When you change the location of web.xml then you have to restart the server to reload web.xml.

Comment: One more thing, don't whether you have use GET method just for testing or not, but while exchanging sensitive data like login always use post.

Answer (score 1):

Change your servlet mapping

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/username/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

to

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/username</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Already done. Nothing changes.

Comment: Consider Kumar's suggestion also and clean your project and diploy it

Answer (score 0):

I have pointed 2-3 things in web.xml.

**first** put **web.xml** in **/WEB-INF** not in **lib**

**second** check servlet name in web.xml. It should be **username** instead of **login**.

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>username</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>sid.username</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

**third** change this

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>username</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/username</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score -1):

By nomenclature class name should start with capital letter and try changing as

```
form action="/username" method="GET"> <br/>
```

User : 
Pass :

in login.jsp and see if this works